# Div box isn't floating where I want it to

Tags: css

I am having problems with floating the boxes on my website where I want them to be.

I want the bottom box "Affiliate Program" placed just under "Your Orders" box. I would really appreciate if someone could tell me what to edit.

Here is the CSS code:

Small left boxes:

```
.small-white-box {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #d9dee1;
    border-radius: 3px;
    width: 230px;
    min-height: 200px;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    color: #37a6ef;
}
```

Big middle box:

```
.large-white-box {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #d9dee1;
    border-radius: 3px;
    width: 665px;
    min-height: 650px;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
div.col-white-box
    div.small-white-box
        ......
    div.small-white-box
        ......
div.large-white-box
    ......
```

css rules

```
.col-white-box {
    float: left;
    width: 252px;
}
.small-white-box {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #d9dee1;
    border-radius: 3px;
    min-height: 200px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    color: #37a6ef;
}
```

Comment: Hey! I tried with that but it's still the same, I am however not sure if I have done it right.

Comment: put the second small-white-box into the col-white-box above

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/theStudent/c42kU/3/

Let me know if that works for you!

**HTML**

```
<div class="content">

<div class="left">    
    <div class="small-white-box"><h2 class="title">Your Orders</h2></div>   
    <div class="small-white-box"><h2 class="title">Affiliate Program</h2>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="right">
    <div class="large-white-box"><h2 class="title">Place Orders</h2>
    Test
    </div>
</div>      
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.content{
    width:100%;
}
.left{
    float:left;
    width: 230px;
    margin: 0 10px 0 0;
}
.right{
    float:left;
    width: 665px;
}
.large-white-box {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #d9dee1;
    border-radius: 3px;
    width: 665px;
    min-height: 650px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    font-size: 14px;
    float:left;
    display:box;

}
.small-white-box {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #d9dee1;
    border-radius: 3px;
    width: 230px;
    min-height: 200px;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    color: #37a6ef;
}
```

Comment: Hey! Where exactly am I supposed to add that, after the 2 small boxes?

Comment: take a look at the code i just did for you. it works but play with the CSS to make it better, i don't have time to make it neat

Comment: Thanks for the help, I didn't try your code as I tested the other post and it fixed my issue, thanks once again for trying to help me!